# Are Cookies in Rails Site based (app based)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies

I have decided to deal with sessions in my application on a cookie level, so I have a session controller that looks like:

```
  module Xaaron
      class SessionsController < ApplicationController

        def new
        end

        def create
          user = Xaaron::User.authenticate_user(params[:user_name], params[:password])
          if sign_in(user)
            if params[:remember_me]
              cookies.permanent[:auth_token] = user.auth_token
            else
              cookies[:auth_token] = user.auth_token
            end
            flash[:notice] = "Welcome back, #{user.first_name}."
            redirect_to root_path
          else
            flash[:alert] = "You have entered incorrect credentials."
            redirect_to login_path
          end
        end

        def destroy
          cookies.delete(:auth_token)
          redirect_to root_path
        end
      end
  end
```

My application is kind of a "gate keeper" application so the user can login into say `site.com` and from there go to `product1.site.com`, their information such as user name, api key, all that jazz is shared between these two apps via [promiscuous](https://github.com/promiscuous-io/promiscuous) gem.

How ever my question is:

**is the cookie created in `site.com` viable for use in `product1.site.com` thus allowing me to use specific helper methods such as: `current_user` in `product1.site.com` to see if said user is logged in?**

The purpose for this is that *if user A is not signed into `site.com` they cannot access `product1.site.com`*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RFC 6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265) has the answer in section 4.1.2.3. If the cookie domain attribute is set to **dom.ain**, then the cookie is sent by the user agent when making requests to **dom.ain**, **[www.dom.ain](http://www.dom.ain)**, **sub.dom.ain**, and other subdomains of **dom.ain**. You can control the cookie domain attribute via the domain key in the cookies hash, like this

```
cookies.signed[:secure_session] = {domain: 'dom.ain', value: "#{user.salt}#{user.id}"}
```